# Languages to use for console tools - Go, Rust, Javascript?

Tags: command-line, utilities, deployment

I'm planning to write a data cruncher command line tool, I'm considering Go, Rust and Javascript. But I'm afraid of jeopardising the project by using something not stable enough or painful to deploy.

Are there examples of widespread packages carried by many distributions written in Go?

And if I want to either write in javascript or evaluate javascript from another language, what are my options? I know there's node.js, but it looks like a huge dependency. Are there examples of UNIX tools written in Javascript?

Am I right to assume that Rust is not ready yet in the same sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of widely-used tools written in any of those languages.  Node.js is not any bigger a dependency than perl or python, though perhaps not as commonly installed.  I actually just installed node 0.12 yesterday on a Windows system with no trouble.

My question is - why not C, python, perl, php, awk, bash script, or tcl?  All have long histories and are widely available.

Comment: C is a bit rough and other ones incur performance overhead, being interpreted languages. Thanks for response tho.